# Javascript Regex - Strip out parameter from listed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, excel

I am trying to build a jquery plugin that locate excel formula and evaluate it, currently using [jison](http://zaach.github.io/jison/) as parser and some regex for placeholder replacement, and the problem is I am blind about those two, the full code currently is in [github](https://github.com/ikhsan017/calx)

What I want to do:

Say I have a registered formula member and it's function

```
var formula = {
    member:['MAX','MIN','AVG','SUM'],
    max:function(cell1,cell2){
        ...
        //return the max
    }
    //.... and other function not listed
}
```

and have an HTML element with data-formula attribute

```
<div data-formula="MAX($A1,$A5)"></div>
```

if the variable placeholder $A1 acted as parameter of listed formula (MAX,MIN,SUM, and AVG) it should replaced by 1.1 (convert A to 1 and concatenate with dot), and if it outside the formula bracket, it should kept remain and will be replaced later (if you could help build jison file that make the MAX() accept string, that would be great :) )

my current code is look like below

```
var $equation = '';
var $formula_regex  = new RegExp('['+formula.member.join('|')+']+\(([^]+)\)','g');
//should be [SUM|AVG|MAX|MIN]+\(([^]+)\)

//this.data[$key].formula contains the string formula
$equation  = this.data[$key].formula.replace($formula_regex,function($range){
$range = $range.replace(/\$\w+/g, function($key) {
    $key = $key.replace('$','');

        //utility.translaceCell will convert B23 to 2.23, C2 to 3.2 etc
    $key = utility.translateCell($key,'string');
    return $key;
});
    return($range);
});
```

above regex work as expected when it contain single formula like MAX($B1,$B3)

```
MAX($B1,$B3) 
//translated to MAX(2.1,2.3)
```

but not work when contain more complex formula

```
IF($B1 > 3,SUM($B1,$B3),MIN($B1,$B3))
//translated to IF(2.1 > 3,SUM(2.1,2.3),MIN(2.1,2.3))
//expected IF($B1 > 3,SUM(2.1,2.3),MIN(2.1,2.3))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Regex:

```
(SUM|AVG|MAX|MIN)\(([^(^)]*)\)
```

With `IF($B1 > 3,SUM($B4,$B5),MIN($B1,$B3))` would match `SUM($B4,$B5)`, `MIN($B1,$B3)` and the matched groups are `$B4,$B5`, `$B1,$B3`

Tested on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

In your code, modify this line:

```
var $formula_regex  = new RegExp('('+formula.member.join('|')+')\(([^(^)]*)\)','g');
```

Comment: I just try it, the regex string is below
(MAX|MIN|SUM|AVG)(([^(^)]*))

test against formula
IF($B1 > 3,SUM($B1,$B3),MIN($B1,$B3))

and the result is
["SUM", "SUM", "", ""]

using exec()
$formula_regex.exec(this.data[$key].formula

Comment: just add more escaping to $formula_regex

$formula_regex, need more escaping var $formula_regex  = new RegExp('('+formula.member.join('|')+')\\(([^(^)]*)\\)','g');

thanks